# Creating a list with specified values in specified positions

Tags: python, list, indexing, replace

I want to create a list given a list of values and a list of positions.

For example, suppose the lists of values and positions are

```
lst1 = [[8,9],[6,7]]
```

and

```
lst2=[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,3],[2,4]],[[1,4],[2,3]]].
```

I want to create the list

```
result=[[8,8,9,9],[8,9,8,9],[8,9,9,8],[6,6,7,7],[6,7,6,7],[6,7,7,6]].
```

The first element of the list result has value `lst1[0][0]` corresponding to the position `lst2[0][0][0]` and `lst2[0][0][1]`. It also has value `lst1[0][1]` corresponding to the position `lst2[0][1][0]` and `lst2[0][1][1]`.

The second element of the result has value `lst1[0][0]` corresponding to the position `lst2[1][0][0]` and `lst[1][0][1]` and value `lst1[0][1]` corresponding to the position `lst2[1][1][0]` and `lst[1][1][1]`.

So far all I can think of is first creating a list of result, and then replacing the elements in this list using by values in lst1 using lst2 to index the elements. But I found this very inefficient. What's the most efficient way to do this?

edit: Orginally, `lst1=[[a,b],[b,a]]`. I just realized that I want the elements to be an integer instead of a string. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation how `result` is related to `lst1` and `lst2`.

Comment: Sorry for being confusing. lst2 specifies the position while lst1 specified the value of that position. So for each element in lst1 (e.g. [a,b]) and each element in lst2 (e.g. [[1,3],[2,4]]), I want to create an element whose 1st and 3rd position is "a" and 2nd and 4th position is "b" (e.g. [a,b,a,b]). Hope this clarifies the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension that combines values and relative positions in tuples, sorts them and builds the result from the values matching the sorted positions.

```
result = [ [v for _,v in sorted((p,v) for v,pv in zip(v1,v2) for p in pv)]
           for v1 in lst1
           for v2 in lst2 ]

print(*result,sep="\n")

['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'b', 'a']
['c', 'c', 'd', 'd']
['c', 'd', 'c', 'd']
['c', 'd', 'd', 'c']
```

with numeric values in list1:

```
[8, 8, 9, 9]
[8, 9, 8, 9]
[8, 9, 9, 8]
[6, 6, 7, 7]
[6, 7, 6, 7]
[6, 7, 7, 6]
```

Comment: Sorry I just realized that I made the mistake in writing the elements of lst1 as a string. In my code it should be an integer value, which is not iterable. So lst1 should be [[1,2],[2,1]]. Is there a way to address this? Thanks!

Comment: Numeric or string doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Oh yes you are right. I found where I got wrong. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try (note: you probably have the last `c`/`d` in your results swapped):

```py
lst1 = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
lst2 = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[1, 3], [2, 4]], [[1, 4], [2, 3]]]

out = []
for l in lst1:
    for subl in lst2:
        m = {k: v for v, subl2 in zip(l, subl) for k in subl2}
        tmp, idx = [], 1
        for subl2 in subl:
            for _ in subl2:
                tmp.append(m[idx])
                idx += 1
        out.append(tmp)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    ["a", "a", "b", "b"],
    ["a", "b", "a", "b"],
    ["a", "b", "b", "a"],
    ["c", "c", "d", "d"],
    ["c", "d", "c", "d"],
    ["c", "d", "d", "c"],
]
```

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that I want the elements in lst1 to be int instead of string. But now zip does not work on int. I'm wondering if there is another way around it? Sorry for the confusion. I just edited my original post.